# Syntax error when nesting STR inside custom formatting?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to convert a number to a string with STR, and give it custom number formatting.

Currently, I tried to nest the two:

```
   DECLARE
@Num float

SET
@Num = 222.33339

SELECT 
  FORMAT(STR(@Num,(8), 4), #,##0.00)
/*String(Original Number, Total Length of Number, Length of Decimal Places)*/

FROM
  Sample
```

But I am receiving a syntax error in my Format function. I've tried debugging but I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't need both `STR` and `FORMAT`, just one or the other.

Comment: would you please explain what you are trying to do are you trying to convert some specific `Curreny` OR `Number` or just put here input value and expected result

Comment: @RBarryYoung - now I know!

Comment: @tinka I'm trying to convert a number to a string, with custom formatting like so: ##0.00## - but updated dynamically using four variables. 

For example, I want to be able to change the minimum number of decimal places, or the maximum number of integers.

Comment: @Avi Siyual solved problem

Comment: @tinka I realized and accepted his answer, just wanted to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `Format` function to be:

```
SELECT FORMAT(@Num, N'#,##0.00')
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! It does fix the syntax issue, but what should I do about the string function that was inside?

Comment: @Avi `Str` should not be needed at all.  `Format` already returns a `varchar`, and if you need to reformat that result, you just need to adjust your mask.

Comment: @Siyual is any difference in `FORMAT(@Num, 'N', 'en-us')` and `FORMAT(@Num, N'#,##0.00')`

Comment: @tinka Technically, no.  `Format(column, 'N', 'en-US')` defaults to `Format(column, N'#,#.00')` which is essentially the same mask the OP was using.

Comment: @Siyual thank you for teaching me! Do you have any suggestion for how to update formatting dynamically?

For example, instead of hardcoding it like ##0.00## - is there a way to do it the same with multiple variables? The way I need to use it ts that for each row there are different minimum and maximum decimal and integer places.